# Read Multiple Integers From line - C

Tags: c, file, scanf

I am trying to read multiple integers from a 500Mb text file where the integers are int the format

```
1000002 1 55
1000002 1000006 33
1000002 1000007 8
1000002 1000009 144
```

When i try and read the integers i have the problem where the program does not read enough the entire file and of that file that it read's it does not seem to be the correct values my code is

```
FILE *file;
    file = fopen("user_artist_data.txt", "r");
    int User_ID, artist_ID, Play_Count = 0;
    int check = 0;
    while(fscanf(file, "%d %d %d", &User_ID, &artist_ID, &Play_Count) != 0)
    {
        check++;
        printf("%d %d %d\n", User_ID, artist_ID, Play_Count);
    }
    fclose(file);
```

Can you please help me with fixing my code. 
Thank you

Comment: First of all try checking out if there is some error on read and see the `errno` value and its text representation with `strerror(errno)` right after you quit the loop and before closing `file`.

Comment: Are you programming in TurboC with 16 bit integers ?

Comment: i'm using GCC on OS X

Comment: Then there is something you are no telling us.  Can you post the input file to a file-sharing site so we can verify the actual format and contents? Compressing it with bzip2 or gzip will reduce the size considerably.

Answer (score 1):

Read *carefully* the documentation of [fscanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fscanf.3.html) (you probably should read it more than once).

Then you'll understand that you probably should code

```
while(fscanf(file, " %d %d %d", &User_ID, &artist_ID, &Play_Count) == 3)
```

<sup>(notice that spaces are handled like newlines by `fscanf`)</sup>

BTW, if your file is line oriented, you'll better read each line with e.g. [getline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) (or else `fgets` if `getline` is not available) then parse each line with [sscanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sscanf.3.html). The `%n` conversion specification is probably very useful.

Don't forget to compile with all warnings and debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) and to use your debugger (e.g.  `gdb`)

Comment: well, he might use format either and put `fscanf` with `%d %d %d\n`.

Comment: No, `\n` is the same as a space for `fscanf`

Comment: I changed my code but when i run it fscanf actually returns 3 so the loop is not run, is there a reason it's doing that. I am going to try with getline now

Comment: You probably don't want any whitespace in the format string, as `%d` skips whitespace automatically.

Comment: well i copied the line of code about which has != 3 and as it is its run. But i did change it to == 3 but that gives the same result i had earlier

Comment: what if there is an empty line (just '\n') in the middle of the file?. the correct scanf test should be against EOF. not agains 3.

Comment: @milevyo: empty lines will be ignored by `fscanf` for format `%d` like any other white space.  Any non numeric data in the input file will cause `fscanf` to stop parsing, returning an incomplete count the first time and a zero count each subsequent time, looping forever if you just test `!= EOF`.